Test environment has been torn down when DataSource.initialize() in ESM project
I created ESM project with TypeORM.
The project has some test files for running jest, but when run npm run test, only the test cases in first test file is success, and other file cases are failure.
The error log is below
> test-ts-esm-typeorm-jest@1.0.0 test /workspaces/test-ts-esm-typeorm-jest
> node --experimental-vm-modules ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js

(node:13541) ExperimentalWarning: VM Modules is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
 PASS  tests/get-user.test.ts
 FAIL  tests/create-user.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Test environment has been torn down

      18 | })
      19 |
    > 20 | await AppDataSource.initialize()
         | ^
      21 | export {AppDataSource}

      at invariant (node_modules/.pnpm/jest-util@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-util/build/invariant.js:16:11)
          at async Promise.all (index 0)
      at src/data-source.ts:20:1

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.696 s, estimated 3 s
Ran all test suites.
 ELIFECYCLE  Test failed. See above for more details.

The Project is shown this repository.
https://github.com/suehiro24/esm-typerom-jest-torndown-reproduction
You can reproduce this by starting devcontaier and doing npm test.
[Expecting]
The DB should be rolled back before and after each test case,
and each test file should connect to the DB correctly.
Inexplicably, the multi-file test succeeds when I run F5 in launch.json.
